# How to find if and where $f(x)$ is continuous and/or differentiable for a given piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

What approach would be ideal in finding if and where $f(x)$ is continuous and/or differentiable when $f$ is a **piecewise** defined function?

A concrete example is below, but I'm interested in *general strategy*, illustrated on this function.

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}     \ln(x) & : x > e\\
    x/e & : x \leq e
  \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only point of potential issue is $x=e$ (why?).

**Continuity**: Evaluate $f(e)$, $\lim_{x\to e^{-}} f(x)$, and $\lim_{x\to e^{+}} f(x)$, and determine whether they are equal or not.

**Differentiability**: Evaluate $\lim_{x\to e^{+}} \frac{f(x)-f(e)}{x-e}$ and $\lim_{x\to e^{-}} \frac{f(x)-f(e)}{x-e}$ and determine whether or not they are equal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Absolutely ideal answer. Gives the solution and an excellent and thorough explanation of all its facets.

Comment: Dear @alx, thanks very much for your kind words! I'm very happy to have helped.